# Handling #include <folder/file.h> in C with makefiles

Tags: c, makefile, include

I am in the process of porting some code that was developed in the codeblocks IDE.  I am transferring it to a Linux server where I can only use the command line to compile the code.  The code is quite large (maybe 100 files) and I need to update the include commands in many files.  For when I try to compile it errors on for instance: `#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>` with a file cannot be found error.  I am assuming it cannot be found because the location of the gsl folder was declared in one of the search directory field options in the IDE.  I could go through each file an update to the correct path, but is there a better way of doing this for use with a makefile?

Thanks!

EDIT Makefile In Question

```
# -c : do not link, just create object file
# -o : output file name

CFLAGS += -c -O2 -I../ctraj -I../cspice/include -I../SGP4 -I../cconj -I../GSL-1.13/include 
LIBS = -L../ctraj -lctraj -L../cspice/lib -lcspice -L../SGP4 -lsgp4 -L../cconj -lcconj -L./ -lgsl-0 -lgslcblas-0 -lm
DEPS = light.h ../ctraj/ctraj.h ../cconj/cconj.h
OBJ = light.o tle.o propagator.o orbitfit.o conjunction.o light_displacement.o forces_LF.o
OUT = light.exe

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
gcc -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

light: $(OBJ)
cd ../ctraj/; make
gcc -o $(OUT) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

clean:
rm *.o $(OUT)
```

Edit 2

Folder Structure

light->(GSL-1.13, Light, cconj, ctraj)

the makefile is inside the Light folder.

Error Message

```
cd ../ctraj/; make
make[1]: Entering directory `/light/ctraj'
gcc -o forces.o forces.c -c -Wall -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -O2 -I../cspice/include -Inrlmsise
In file included from ../Light/../cconj/cconj.h:12:0,
             from ../Light/light.h:13,
             from forces.c:3:
../Light/../cconj/../GSL-1.13/include/gsl/gsl_blas.h:26:28: fatal error: gsl/gsl_vector.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [forces.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory /light/ctraj'
make: *** [light] Error 2
```

EDIT 3

Second makefile in cconj

```
# -c : do not link, just create object file
# -o : output file name
#-L../cconj -lcconj 

CFLAGS += -c -O2 -I./ -I../GSL-1.13/include 
LIBS = -L./ -lgsl-0 -lgslcblas-0 -lm
INC= -I../GSL-1.13/include
DEPS = cconj.h 
OBJ = cconj_util.o ellipse_intersect.o collision_prob_real.o rcs2size.o
OUT = libcconj.a

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
gcc -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

cconj: $(OBJ)
ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ) 

clean:
rm *.o $(OUT)
```

Comment: The answer is simple, but it would help if you showed us the rule and the location of `gsl/`.

Comment: the path is ../GSL-1.13/include/gsl/gsl_math.h

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line to your makefile, and tell us if it works:

```
CFLAGS += -I../GSL-1.13/include
```

In order to compile source code and produce object files, Make must use a rule. (If you don't put such a rule in the makefile, Make has a default rule for that purpose.) It looks something like this:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Without digging too deeply into how that works, we can say that `CFLAGS` is a list of arguments to be passed to the compiler. When we add `-I../GSL-1.13/include`, we tell the compiler "if you want to #include something and can't find it elsewhere, look in ../GSL-1.13/include".

If this approach doesn't work, then there's probably a rule in the makefile we must find and alter.

**EDIT:**

The problem isn't in this makefile (which already contains a reference to `GSL-1.13/include`). In this command:

```
cd ../ctraj/; make
```

this makefile launches a second Make process, which uses the Makefile in `light/cconj/`. According to the compiler output (`gcc -o forces.o ...`), that makefile does *not* include the reference. So try adding the same line there, and if that doesn't work, post that makefile and we'll keep looking.

Comment: did not seem to work, I have uploaded my makefile to the original post

Comment: @PumpkinPie: That's helpful. Could you also post the error message, so that we can see which file it is trying to build?

Comment: Ok, the error message is there and I have include a folder hierarchy

Comment: Nevermind it worked, I was just and idiot and was not updating the correct 2nd makefile.  THanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Use -I option of gcc to specify where to look for includes.